# C++ Binary search like lower_bound

Tags: c++, search, binary

I do have problem with my binary search which should work a little like lower_bound. This gives me a segfault in 5th run. Can anyone see a problem ? Thanks

```
int BinarySearch ( const char * a, int firstindex , int lastindex){
    if (m_len == 0) return 0; //number of items in searched array
    if ( firstindex == lastindex ) return lastindex;
    int tmp = lastindex - firstindex;
    int pos = tmp/2;
    if ( tmp % 2 != 0 ) ++pos;
    if (strcmp(a,Arr[pos]) < 0) return BinarySearch(a,firstindex,pos-1);
    if (strcmp(a,name) > 0) return BinarySearch(a,pos+1,lastindex);
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Breaking Bytes hehehehe

Comment: I'm not sure you even need it in your code. Anyway `if ( tmp % 2 != 0 )` is equivalent to `if ( tmp % 2 == 1)` which is equivalent to `if ( tmp % 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `int tmp = lastindex - firstindex;`

Should be:

```
int tmp = lastindex + firstindex;
```

That is because you are looking for the middle of the indexes x and y which is (x+y)/2.

Your code's behaviour should be unpredictable, possibly looping and causing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint between x and y is x + (y - x)/2, so you want

```
int pos = firstIndex + tmp/2;
```

Using the slightly more complex expression instead of the obvious (x + y)/2 eliminates an overflow bug that is very common.

Comment: (x+y)/2 is simpler, isn't it?

Comment: @dingalapadum That has the potential for arithmetic overflow. This is the correct way of doing what you seem to want, and should be considered a general solution even if you're "certain" you'll never risk such overflow.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't want anything. But ok, I see your point that the proposed solution is more robust.

Comment: @dingalapadum Sry, I really should pay more attention to who posts questions vs. comments. Thought you were the OP. Good that you see the reason behind the difference with `(x+y)/2`. Disappointed the OP *didn't*.